# What's wrong in my argument?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

The limit $\lim_{n \to \infty}\left( \frac{3^n}{2^n}\right)=\infty $ might be rewritten as $\lim_{n \to \infty}\left( \frac{3}{2}\right)^n=\infty.$

But what if $\frac{\ln(3)}{\ln(2)}$ instead?

Let’s say:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{n \ln 3}{n \ln 2}\right)=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{ \ln 3}{ \ln 2}\right)=\frac{ \ln 3}{ \ln 2}$$

What's wrong in the argument?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: $\ln (\frac {3^n}{2^n}) \ne \frac {\ln 3^n}{\ln 2^n}$.  It is true that $\lim  \frac {\ln 3^n}{\ln 2^n} = \frac {\ln 3}{\ln 2}$ because $ \frac {\ln 3^n}{\ln 2^n}=\frac {\ln 3}{\ln 2}$ but $\lim \ln (\frac {3^n}{2^n})= \infty$ because   $\ln (\frac {3^n}{2^n}) = n\ln \frac 32$.

Comment: The thing that is wrong is that there is no connection between $(\frac 32)^n$ and $\frac{n\log 3}{n\log 2}$.

Comment: Well, there *IS* a connection.  One is the ratio of logs of the corresponding numerator and denominator of the other.  It's just that such a connection has no pertinence to limits or to much of anything and I don't believe any generalizations about values are relative sizes can be made from it.  (I believe any value con be manipulated in this manner to any other value by a proper choose of scale and .... oh, I'll just stop typing now....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\ln (\frac {3^n}{2^n}) \ne \frac {\ln 3^n}{\ln 2^n}$.

It is true that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}  \frac {\ln 3^n}{\ln 2^n} = \frac {\ln 3}{\ln 2}$ because $ \frac {\ln 3^n}{\ln 2^n}=\frac {\ln 3}{\ln 2}$ but $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \ln (\frac {3^n}{2^n})= \infty$ because   $\ln (\frac {3^n}{2^n}) = n\ln \frac 32$.

$\frac {\ln 3}{\ln 2} \ne n\cdot \ln \frac 32$ so there is no reason to assume  $\lim \frac {\ln 3}{\ln 2}$ to equal $\lim n\cdot \ln \frac 32$.

Comment: In my understanding I could apply the same operations on the denominator and quotient and still have same fraction. Let’s say 2/3 * a/a = 2/3. Why not with logarithmic?

Comment: "In my understanding I could apply the same operations on the denominator and quotient and still have same fraction."  I'm not sure how you came about that understanding but it is utterly wrong.  $\frac ab \ne \frac {a+5}{b+5}$ and $\frac ab\ne\frac {a^2}{b^2}$ and the *only* operation I can think of where this *is* true is multiplication by constant (which only works because division is the inverse of multiplication and so the multiplications "cancel out" when you divide).  It *certainly* is *not* true that $\frac ab = \frac {\ln a}{\ln b}$.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your calculations.

There should not be any argument because you have found two different limits correctly.

Note that the second fraction is not a power but the ratio of two powers so it is not similar  to the first one and we don't expect the similar result.

Answer (score 0):

$\ln\left(\dfrac{3^n}{2^n}\right)=\ln\left(\dfrac32\right)^n=n\ln\left(\dfrac32\right)=n(\ln3-\ln2)=n\ln3-n\ln2,$ not ${n\ln3}\div{n\ln2}$

Comment: I think I edited my post within $5$ minutes of posting so time edited is not reported; so you could delete your comment

Comment: oh, that's why i don't see the edit tag on my answer either.